# How to make a textbox invisible based on the choice of a dropdown in dynamically generated GUI

Tags: jquery, html

When ChoiceC is chosen in the drop down menu I want to make the "Other" textbox invisible and bring it back otherwise.  Am I not writing my function correctly? It should be called on every change of value in the DropDown right?  The HTML here is from a 'View Source' command because the GUI is generated dynamically.

```
<label>
Please Specify
</label>

<select name="ctl00$ctl00$cphMainContent$cphContent$dd-140" 
      id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphContent_dd-140" 
 data-qid="140">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="ChoiceA">A</option>
        <option value="ChoiceB">B</option>
        <option value="ChoiceC">C</option>

</select>


<label>
Other
</label>

<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphMainContent$cphContent$txt-139" 
     id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphContent_txt-139" 
 data-qid="139"/>
<span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphContent_reqValidator_txt_139" 





 <script>
 $(
  function ()
  {
    if ($("#data-qid='140'").val() == 'ChoiceC')
        $("#data-qid='139'").hide();
  }
  );
 </script>
```

Comment: looks like your missing the function call. Change event on select is not there, although this may go away in this view since its not the original code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the `change` event of the select dropdown to identify the value entered and then based on the value, you can show/hide the input field. Here is a quick example of this in action-

```js
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[data-qid=139]').hide();
  $('input[data-qid=139]').prev().hide();
  $('select[data-qid=140]').on('change', function(e) {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    if(inputValue == 'ChoiceC') {
      $('input[data-qid=139]').hide();
      $('input[data-qid=139]').prev().hide();
    } else {
      $('input[data-qid=139]').show();
      $('input[data-qid=139]').prev().show();
    }
  });
 });
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Please Specify</label>

<select name="ctl00$ctl00$cphMainContent$cphContent$dd-140"  id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphContent_dd-140" data-qid="140">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="ChoiceA">A</option>
        <option value="ChoiceB">B</option>
        <option value="ChoiceC">C</option>
</select>


<label>Other</label>
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphMainContent$cphContent$txt-139" 
     id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphContent_txt-139" 
 data-qid="139"/>
<span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphContent_reqValidator_txt_139"
```

Comment: That works great!  Two quick things.   

How would I make the label "Other" invisible as well 

and how I would get it to be invisible on a page load since it defaults to the blank value.

Comment: To get the label to be invisible, you will have to do it with jQuery using the `prev()` method, since in the above structure your label is the previous sibling for the `input` field. I have updated the answer above to show you that.. However, based on the exact html structure you have, you might need to find out the element using other `jQuery` selectors.

Comment: Nope that works as is!  And to call it on page load?

Comment: You want to hide the input field and the label on page load?

Comment: Yes because it does not default to Choice C

Comment: You can easily do that by using the code in the `if` condition above. Just do that inside `$(document).ready()` so that it fires at page load. Updated above snippet to show you this. On a sidenote, please accept the answer, if your query is resolved.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!